# How to find out the torque constant of BLDC motor?

Tags: electric-machine

I am working on BLDC(Hub) motor for electric vehicle application. In my project i want to control the speed using disturbance observer. For the implementation of disturbance observer there is a requirement of torque constant. In PMDC motor Kt and Ke both are equal but in BLDC they are not equal. Also in data sheet of hub motor (BLDC) they don't mention the torque constant. In my application exact value of torque constant are required.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5326445/

How do I measure the values of a BLDC motor?

[image]

Comment: You look it up in the datasheet.  Duh!

Comment: Apply 1A current (90 degrees!) and measure torque.

Comment: Or you can get it from the speed constant.

Comment: @BrianDrummond wont work... Ke (1/Kv) ~ Kt in theory. They are close enough if a machine magnetics are in the linear region BUT power dense machines where hte stator (esp the teeth) are  around hte knee point then Ke != Kt by a significant amount, at rated current

Comment: @OP Why do you need the exact value of the "torque constant" Kt.   It isn't really a constant and 99 times out of 100 the Ke constant is enough to give you a good enough idea. For those 1 out of 100 either it is a bespoke machine and thus FEA info is available for the true characteristics of Kt (temperature, tolerances, Ld, Lq affect etc) OR the datasheet will explicitly state the difference

Comment: @aman2909 If you really want to measure torque then you'll need something to measure torque (torque wrench, torque meter, a yardstick and a weight or a yardstick and a force gauge). Then you put some current in and measure the torque, do this for several values of current and several measurements for each and graph it out in excel or something.

Comment: "in data sheet of hub motor (BLDC) they don't mention the torque constant." - _which_ motor? If the manufacturer can't be bothered supplying this information then you will just have to measure it yourself (which is the best solution anyway, since manufacturer's specs can't always be trusted).

Comment: But how I can measure torque constant @BruceAbbott  this is my question.

Comment: @BruceAbbott may I know that why would you subtract no load current from current under load. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: No-load current does not produce torque at the shaft (some of it produces _internal_ torque, but that is all used up just spinning the rotor).

Answer (score 0):

To get the 'exact' torque constant (Kt) you will have to measure no-load current (Io), then torque (t) and current under load (I). Kt = t / (I - Io).

For improved accuracy it pays to take several measurements at different loadings, and plot the results. It should be close to a straight line.

Torque must be measured mechanically. One way to do this is with a [pony brake](http://www.amatrol.com/coursepage/electric-motors-training-system/el613-43/).

[image]

Comment: If anyone have any idea regarding this new questions please reply 
  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337304/mechanical-time-constant-of-pmdc-motor-in-starting-and-after-switching-off-the-s