# Mechanical time constant of PMDC Motor in starting and after switching off the supply is same or different?

Tags: dc-motor, control, control-system, brushless-dc-motor, electric-machine

In my **MATLAB/SIMULINK model** of the PMDC motor the mechanical time constant has same value in the case  starting of motor and after switching off the supply but in **experimental setup there is a difference?**
I have taken many experimental readings, in which starting mechanical time constant is around 0.05 seconds and after switching off the mechanical time constants is around 0.254 seconds.
[image: SIMULINK Model] .
[image: Starting Mechanical time constant]
[image: After switch off the supply, time constant]

If any one have any idea, please reply me.

Comment: It depends entirely on the load.  In general though, no.  Starting is powered, stopping is unpowered (coasting down).

Comment: In every situation the plant is same i.e. PMDC motor. So in any case transfer function is same. Please see my below reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is that loop what you really have, or are you connecting a low impedance supply across the motor on startup, but open circuiting the motor on switch off?

These conditions are not the same. Switch a short circuit across the motor on switch off and watch the thing comes to a screeching halt (All the K.E. will end up as heat in the motor windings).

Comment: I have exactly this loop except I have neglect inductance value due to very low 0.77mH . The above model is in control form not in Circuit form and also feedback is  natural. Please see my below reply.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your model is showing a similar acceleration & deceleration is because it is a linear representation. This is perfect to derive aspects of the mechanical time constant, but it does not represent a complete system.

Rotating masses accelerate when torque is applied. If the acceleration and deceleration rate are identical in your model it indicate that the "torque" is identical. Why?  because of the \$\frac{1}{s}\$ in the simplified mechanical model.

Consider what integration means when:

1. The initial condition is zero BUT a positive input
2. The initial condition is non-zero BUT zero input...

The rate of change only differs in sign and this is why you are seeing a balanced accel and decel.

In practice you have a source of power to provide acceleration torque & then a frictional component to slow the system down.

In your example you have a voltage source being applied to the stator (represented as just resistance... no inductance). The resultant current, via Kt will produce torque on an body with inertia **J** & a damping fact **B**. The "faster" the rotor spins, the larger the BackEMF, which reduces the forcing voltage which in turn reduces the current which reduces the torque available for acceleration.

The impact of DRAG needs to be capture in a close-loop fashion such that it imposes a torque w.r.t. velocity

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @JonRB In my PMDC motor Inductance is very low 0.77mH, so I neglected it. As you suggested, I have drawn same Simulink Model but I get equal time constant in both case. I have also derive differential equation for both case and get equal time constant.

Comment: that 1/R block... what is it?  it is NOT a gain block, what are you using?

Comment: 1/(SL+R) where inductance is neglected so it reduced to 1/R block.

Comment: @aman2909 that's not what I am asking... A gain block is a triangle in simulink, your 1/R block is square.   What are you using.  Also I would dispute the insignificants of the L

Comment: As you suggested I have used triangle block, then after I got same result. Even adding inductance yet the result same. If you give me your email id then I will send you my simulink model with detailed theoretical analysis.

Comment: Could you put it on a Dropbox/Google drive/FileShare. I just need the MATLAB file. I suspect it is how you are driving it

Comment: @Nick Alexeev  No options for uploading pics in the comment option. That is why I went through this option. Kindly don't delete my that comment. That is helpful in understanding the different aspects.